# Where is a good starting point to learn to Salesforce admin

Tags: administration

I have looked through developer.force.com and gone through a few basic guides on apex. I cant seem to find a real starting point for learning the basics of salesforce admin. The youtube videos and articles I have found never seem to come from the perspective of a completely new user.

Comment: you can start from fundamental from " http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf "

Comment: What's your budget for educational materials? Is an employer helping cover costs?

Comment: The fundamentals pdf is exactly what I was looking for thank you!
I am doing this out of pocket so looking for low cost way of getting into salesforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ADM classes (ADM 201, etc) are a great starting point. They have online and in-house versions available (in-house being obviously pricier). You don't need Apex Code or Visualforce to be an effective admin; your day-to-day chores will involve running reports, managing page layouts and fields, and managing users. It only takes a few basic courses to get going, but you'll find the nuances of security and dashboards will take a little bit longer to get a true grasp on.

If you want to eventually take on a role as a developer, you can advance to the developer courses that salesforce.com offers. I personally recommend learning an offline language like C# or Java first to get your feet wet before attempting to learn Apex Code.

Comment: These are great classes. I had to sign up for a partner program to gain access to these.