# Start a career as Salesforce Admin

Tags: community

I'm a s/w professional with Mainframes background and decent DB2 SQL skills.
I've not worked in Java or any Oops based framework.
With this background, can I think of getting into Salesforce Administration. I'm ready to learn the nitty gritties of salesforce, but given my background how long would it take to train to be a Salesforce admin. Kindly advise!!

Cheers,
Gayatri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is a good starting point to learn to Salesforce admin](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28592/where-is-a-good-starting-point-to-learn-to-salesforce-admin)

Answer (score 4):

I will definitely recommend it. The skill set is very useful and Salesforce.com is the leader in Cloud Computing. The company is growing and so is the developer community.

If you want to dive deeper into Salesforce, but haven’t heard about Trailhead — now is the time. Trailhead is a great training tool provided (for free) that will walk you through the details of various functions within Salesforce. Every skill set is covered; whether you’re a developer or an admin, you’re covered. Many of the admin modules are relatively new and they’re worth a look.

Comment: I'd second the recommendation for Trailhead as it is free and now extremely comprehensive in covering the Admin and Developer skills as well as the business side of CRM.

Comment: Thanky'all for your inputs and yes the Trailhead stuff you pointed out really is comprehensive!! What I specifically want to know is, would it make sense to train to be a Salesforce Admin  without any experience on the SF development side?